# Configuring the Health Check of a Kubernetes Ingress with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gcloud, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-health-check

We are using an ingress (`kubernetes_ingress.db_admin_ingress`) to expose the service (`kubernetes_service.db_admin`) of a deployment (`kubernetes_deployment.db_admin`) in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) with Terraform.

When Terraform creates the ingress, a Level 7 Load Balancer is automatically created with a default health check:

- port: 80
- path: `/`
- protocol: HTTP(S)

Our deployment (`kubernetes_deployment.db_admin`) does not respond to the path `/` with a `200`, so the health check fails.

How can we change the path in the health check configuration?

```hcl
resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "db_admin_ssl_certificate" {
  provider = google-beta

  name = "db-admin-ssl-certificate"

  managed {
    domains = ["db.${var.domain}."]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "db_admin" {
  metadata {
    name = "db-admin"
    labels = {
      App = "db-admin"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = "db-admin"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = "db-admin"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "dpage/pgadmin4:2022-01-10-1"
          name  = "db-admin"
          env {
            name = "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL"
            value = "test@test.com"
          }
          env {
            name = "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD"
            value = "test"
          }      

          port {
            container_port = 80
          }

          resources {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "db_admin" {
  metadata {
    name = "db-admin"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      App = kubernetes_deployment.db_admin.spec.0.template.0.metadata[0].labels.App
    }
    port {
      protocol    = "TCP"
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "NodePort"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "db_admin_ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  
  metadata {
    name = "db-admin-ingress"
    annotations = {
      "ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert"   = google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.db_admin_ssl_certificate.name
    }
  }

  spec {

    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "db-admin"
            service_port = 80
          }

          path = "/*"
        }


      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks), you are able to customize `ingress`/Level 7 Load Balancer health checks through either:

- the `readinessProbe` for the `container` within the `pod` your `ingress` is serving traffic to

  **Warning**: this method comes with warnings [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#interpreted_hc)
- a `backendconfig` resource

I would **highly** recommend creating a `backendconfig` resource.

Unfortunately, the `kubernetes` Terraform provider does **not** seem to support the `backendconfig` resource based on [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/764) GitHub issue.  This means that you can either:

- use the `kubernetes-alpha` provider (found [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes-alpha/0.6.0)) to transcribe a YAML `backendconfig` manifest to HCL with the `manifest` argument for the only `kubernetes-alpha` resource: `kubernetes-manifest` (more on that [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes-alpha/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_manifest))
- use an unofficial provider (such as `banzaicloud/k8s` found [here](https://github.com/banzaicloud/terraform-provider-k8s))
- check the `backendconfig` manifest (as either JSON or YAML) into SCM

A sample `backendconfig` YAML manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: db-admin
  namespace: default
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 30
    timeoutSec: 5
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 2
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /v1/some/path
    port: 80
```

**Note**: a `service` is needed to associate a `backendconfig` with an `ingress`/Level 7 Load Balancer:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-admin-ingress-backend-config
  labels:
    app: db-admin
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"db-admin"}}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: db-admin
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

You can learn more about the `backendconfig` resource and the `service` it requires [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#exercise).